# Multiple VLAN range on Liberty Openstack

Tags: linux, networking, cloud, openstack

We have 3 VLAN (10,20 & 30) in our physical network on Liberty so how do i define three VLAN set in my configuration should i do following in ml2 plugin?

is following method is right?

## /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini

```
type_drivers = vxlan,gre,vlan
network_vlan_ranges = vlan10:10:10,vlan20:20:20,vlan30:30:30
```

## In OVS plugin

```
bridge_mappings = vlan10:br-vlan,vlan20:br-vlan,vlan30:br-vlan
```

## Create Network

```
neutron net-create vlan10 --shared --provider:network_type vlan --provider:segmentation_id 10 --provider:physical_network vlan10 --router:external

neutron net-create vlan20 --shared --provider:network_type vlan --provider:segmentation_id 20 --provider:physical_network vlan20 --router:external

neutron net-create vlan30 --shared --provider:network_type vlan --provider:segmentation_id 30 --provider:physical_network vlan30 --router:external
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you do not need to create individual bridge mappings or physical networks for each VLAN. Use one physical network name mapped to the bridge that has the VLANs.

```
[ovs]
bridge_mappings = physnet:br-vlan
```

Secondly as this is a provider network with specific VLANs that should be used and not a tenant network you do not need to specify a usable VLAN range. A range is typically specified so that VLANs can be handed out to tenant networks from a pool by neutron without admin intervention.

```
[ml2_type_vlan]
network_vlan_ranges = physnet
```

So that a single L3 agent can handle multiple external networks in your l3_agent.ini specify:

```
[DEFAULT]
external_network_bridge =
```

Note that you cannot simply omit the configuration line, you must specify it as empty as the default value is "br-ex".

Finally, your neutron commands will be:

```
neutron net-create vlan10 --shared --provider:network_type vlan --provider:segmentation_id 10 --provider:physical_network physnet --router:external
neutron net-create vlan20 --shared --provider:network_type vlan --provider:segmentation_id 20 --provider:physical_network physnet --router:external
neutron net-create vlan30 --shared --provider:network_type vlan --provider:segmentation_id 30 --provider:physical_network physnet --router:external
```

Comment: Thanks!  If i enable DHCP agent on vlan subnet does that DHCP will interfere on my existing LAN DHCP?